# MongoDB -- Setting a conditional statement in .find()

Tags: mongodb

for aggregate, `$cond` can be used to form an if-statement. I'm wonder if there's a similar function for .find()

When I tried using $cond in find(), I get

```
"unknown top level operator: $cond"
```

I'm trying to do the following (in pseudo code):

```
if condition is True:
    set filter for find to thing_1
else:
    set filter for find to thing_2
```

Comment: why don't you create two different queries and pass it?

Comment: this whole thing becomes a string and is stored in a database. I'm trying to follow suit and form that one string only. Unless I can use an OR somehow

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mongo 3.6 or greater, you could try using the `$expr` operator. Which would then allow you to use `$cond`.

> `$expr` Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

Their example can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#using-expr-with-conditional-statements)

```
db.supplies.find( {
    $expr: {
       $lt:[ {
          $cond: {
             if: { $gte: ["$qty", 100] },
             then: { $divide: ["$price", 2] },
             else: { $divide: ["$price", 4] }
           }
       },
       5 ] }
} )
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I be able to use this through the mongodb compass app?