# MongoDB Java conditional find

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB ( collection with documents possibly containing two dates, `dateA` and `dateB`. These dates aren't guaranteed to be set, and can be null.

I want to write a find query that expresses:

```
    if dateA is not null:
            if dateA is less than someArbitraryDate
    or
    if dateB is not null:
            if dateB is less than someArbitraryDate
```

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082423/mongodb-setting-a-conditional-statement-in-find), I know I probably need to use `$expr` and `$cond`.
I'm just not sure how to write the find.

Comment: are you saying you want the query alone? or do you need it in spring data?

Comment: I'm not using spring, just the Java driver. I think the query alone would suffice for me to figure out how to use it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `$expr` or `$cond` for the simple use case that you stated. We can achieve the same with just `$or`.

The query will be something like:

```
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        {"dateA": {"$exists": true, "$ne": null, "$lt":  ISODate("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>")}},
        {"dateB": {"$exists": true, "$ne": null, "$lt":  ISODate("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>")}},
    ]
})
```

Here `$exists` ensures the field is present, `$ne: null` ensures the value is not null and then just a less than match to a date string will give you what you want in one if-if block you wrote

Combining them with `$or` will just combine the results from each of the `dateA` and `dateB` matches.

Read more on the operators from: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/

Comment: Good point. I think this should work for my scenario, thanks!