# mongodb pipeline: how to implement "if-else"?

Tags: mongodb

I'm pretty new to mongo and databases in general. For my problem, I have a collection of documents with schema

```
user: {
    name: String, //first name
    username: String,
    id: Number,
    team: String,
    state: String,
}
```

In this case, only `team` and `state` are relevant. State of the documents are either `Alive` or `Dead`. I'm hoping to automate the following process:

if state is `Alive`, set team to `A`
otherwise (state is `Dead`), set team to `B` and set state to `Alive`

in node, for the first part I have written

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'user.state': 'Alive'
    }
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'user.team': 'A'
    }
  }
]
```

I'm hoping to learn how to do this with pipelining/aggregations. I can do each of the cases individually with by using $match and $set, but I don't know how to combine the cases.

Comment: try [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator they have provided well syntax and example.

Comment: here is the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082423/mongodb-setting-a-conditional-statement-in-find for find() but the condition is similar for aggregation.

Comment: Use Like this:    "$cond": [
         {
          "$and": [{
           "$eq": [
            "$year",
            { "$year": new Date() }
           ]
          },
          {
           "$eq": [
            "$week",
            { "$week": new Date() }
           ]
          }]
         },
         "$totalPrice",
         0
        ]